# How to control output width when use knitr to compile to pdf?

Tags: r, knitr

using knitr to compile to a .Rnw document to a pdf, the width of output text in a chunk can not be resetted by out.width option.
[image]

how to keep the output text in area with the background color?

Answer (score 4):

The text output width in PDF is always a painful problem. It is not easy to make sure everything fits on [a page](http://yihui.name/en/2013/10/markdown-or-latex/). Two possible and general solutions (if you have to use LaTeX/PDF):

1. make the white margin smaller in LaTeX, e.g.

   ```
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
   ```
2. make the text output narrower in R, e.g.

   ```
   options(width = 60)
   ```

Note these solutions are not guaranteed to work, because you can never be sure how wide the text output can be, and some output functions do not respect the `width` option. For example, it is almost impossible to make this work:

```
cat('This is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long string. Haha.\n')
```

There are some LaTeX packages such as `listings` that can wrap the verbatim output, but that can also lead to ugly output. For example, if the natural output from R is this (suppose the two lines are too wide):

```
text output wrapped by R
and then wrapped by LaTeX
```

LaTeX wrapping can turn it to this:

```
text output wrapped
by R
and then wrapped by
LaTeX
```

For your specific application of showing a contingency table, my suggestion is to transpose the table (`t(table(...))`) and print it.