# RMarkdown pdf document chunk output exceeds page margins

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown

While I am knitting a document as a PDF using RMarkdown some code chunk outputs exceeds the page margins as seen on the pic.

Any ideas to fix this?

[image: image path]

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490837/how-to-control-output-width-when-use-knitr-to-compile-to-pdf? [Link to the doc](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/#long-lines-of-text-output).

Comment: Yep... no chance..

Answer (score 3):

Many functions do not respond correctly to the page size config. So to solve such an issue, you have to include the following configuration for the output file.

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: --listings
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
```

create the file `preamble.tex` in the same folder where the Rmarkdown file exists, and its content is the following:

```
\lstset{
  breaklines=true
}
```

For more information, check https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/text-width.html.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem could be the typo, not *widt*

```
options(width = 60) ## I usually use 50 -60
```